# acmsmall: accented upper-case characters and line spacing

Tags: line-spacing, acm

I am currently using the [acmsmall](http://www.acm.org/publications/submissions/latex_style) document class.

I have noticed that upper-case accented characters such as "Å" and "Ä" will result in uneven line spacing. MWE:

```
\documentclass[prodmode]{acmsmall}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \AA test \lipsum[2] \"Atest \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Moreover, the style enforces the author-year format of citations, which makes it impossible to avoid such characters in running text (some authors happen to have accents in their names).

What kind of kludges are available to avoid ugly line spacing in this situation?

---

**Edit:** A related question: Can I somehow easily *find* all instances of uneven line spacing, other than trying to spot them by staring at the PDF file? For example, can I add some special code in the preamble to make sure that Latex prints a warning whenever there are "too high" characters (or, for example, equations)?

Comment: No, it's not possible or at least very difficult to get warned. If you provisionally set `\lineskip=30pt` you'll get large white spaces in case there's clash between ascenders and descenders.

Comment: @egreg: Great, this is a very useful trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class sets very tight line spacing (10/11), so these problems are unavoidable without a specially crafted font.

I've prepared two examples, by adding `\smash{\AA rno}` in the first paragraph of the sample article.

### Example 1 (acceptable)

[image]

### Example 2 (unacceptable)

[image]

One could think to write all names in smaller size small-caps, but this would require changing the whole author-year style mechanism.

You can easily obtain the unacceptable version by saying

```
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen}
```

in your preamble.

If you have a small number of accented names, you can type normally; then look at where they fall and reword the paragraph until clashes between ascenders and descenders don't happen. Or forget about that and keep the clashes.

Changing the baselineskip is an option, but it couldn't be accepted by the journal editors.

They just didn't think that people can have accents in their names and *do* care about having them printed right.

Comment: Thanks, manual `\smash`ing of the offending citations seems to work fairly well, combined with the rewording of the paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The previous line with a q has

```
...\hbox(7.40997+2.04993)x396.0, glue set 0.23616
```

so depth 2 and a bit points  the height of `AA` is 9.07591pt, the sum of which is more than the specified baselineskip of 11pt. If you changed the baselineskip to 11.1 pt things would be more even.

acmsmall has

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{11\p@}%
  \abovedisplayskip .5\baselineskip \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@minus 3\p@
  \let\@listi\@listI
}
```

You could repeat that definition in the preamble between `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` and change `11` to `11.5` or something.